# Code not working (python)

Tags: python, scipy

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import scipy.integrate as spi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G=6.67*10**(-11)
M=6.4*(10**23)
R=3.4*(10**6)
m=260
#define the gravitational constant G, radius (R) and mass (M) of Mars and the mass of the satellite (m)

#called with the variables to be differentiated
def f(a,t):
  xx=a[0]
  vx=a[1]
  yy=a[2]
  vy=a[3]
  ax=-(G*M*xx)/((xx**2+yy**2)**1.5)
  ay=(-G*M*yy)/((xx**2+yy**2)**1.5)
  return [vx,ax,vy,ay]
#returns differentiated values, function defines values and returns new values

d=((xx**2+yy*2)**(0.5))

if d<r:
    vx,vy,ax,ay=0,0,0,0
    return [vx,ax,vy,ay]

#first initial conditions- blue curve

t1=sp.linspace(0.,259200,10000) #three years

initial1=[3*R,2000,3*R,500]

solution1=spi.odient(f,initial1,t1)

x1=solution1[:,0]
y1=solution1[:,2]

pl.figure(1)
pl.plot(x1,y1)
pl.xlabel("x")
pl.ylabel("y")
pl.show()
```

Hi there please could you help me to get this code running! It is written in python and is fairly basic, I have an error with the second return function, it says 'return' outside function. The other error is "'module' object has no attribute 'odient'".

Comment: because... it's not in a function?

Comment: your formatting is incorrect and you are definitely calling return outside of a function.

Comment: I'm not addressing your question.  I just want to point out that an easier (less computation) way of expressing your constants is with scientific notation, e.g., ``G = 6.67e-11`` and ``M = 6.4e23``.

Comment: ... and the method should be `odeint`, not `odient`.

Comment: Could you please edit your title? "Code Not Working" isn't going to help anyone who needs the same answer as you find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if d<r:
    vx,vy,ax,ay=0,0,0,0
    return [vx,ax,vy,ay]
```

This isn't a function so you can't use `return`. If you want to add those values to a list you can make a new list:

```
new_list = [vx,ax,vy,ay]
```

You don't need to use return outside of a function because those variables are already in scope. When you use variables inside a function they aren't in the same scope as the rest of your program. For example:

```
>>> def foo():
        a =10
>>> a = 1
>>> foo()
>>> a
1
```

The `a` inside the function doesn't effect the `a` outside of. In you `if` statement you don't need a `return` because it is in the same scope. The assignment of the variables doesn't need to be returned from anywhere because it's the same scope.

And as @Hugh Bothwell pointed out you have a typo in your function call should be:

```
scipy.integrate.odeint()
```